# SCCM 2012: SQL Server service running account

Tags: sql-server, sccm, sccm-2012

When installing System Center Configuration Manager 2012, one of the problems I encountered during the Prerequisite Check was "SQL Server service running account". The detail of the prerequisite check is:

> The logon account for the SQL Server service cannot be a local user account, NT SERVICE\ or LOCAL SERVICE. You must configure the SQL Server service to use a valid domain account, NETWORK SERVICE, or LOCAL SYSTEM.

On the machine with my Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Enterprise installation, I have deleted all the servers except for the reserved account (sa) and the domain account I used to log into the server with (domain\administrator), as per the above error message. However, I continue to receive the above failed requisite error. Are there any other checks I could do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it was a configuration error on one of the installation steps. According to [this guide](http://matthewdpeters.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/installing-sql-server-2008-for-use-with-system-center-configuration-manager-2012-rc):

> On the Server Configuration screen I choose the accounts I set up earlier in Active Directory Users and Computers (if you haven’t done it yet, you can do it now). The passwords that have been set for the accounts go here too. Change the Startup Type of the SQL Server Agent service to Automatic in the dropdown box. Also change the SQL Server Browser Startup Type to Automatic.

This resolved the issue.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this is exactly what my answer says as well.

Answer (score 4):

A step by step instruction can be found here:

http://www.randomtechtips.com/change-logon-account-for-sql-server-service/

1 – Create a dedicate domain account to be used for the SQL Server Service – don’t get into the habit of using your own domain admin account to run services – systems will break when you leave and your reputation will be shot!

2 – Using your Admin tools, open Active Directory Users and Computers

3 – Right-click on an Organizational Unit that will contain your domain user account

4 – Click New, User, create a user account with a meaningful name, with a meaningful description

5 – On the SQL Server, click Start, SQL Server Configuration Manager

6 – Click SQL Server Services, in the right window pane, right-click SQL Server , click Properties

7 – Click the Log On tab, click “This account”, click browse

8- Select the Run Account created earlier

9 – Enter the password (twice to confirm) in the Log on tab, click OK.  When prompted to Confirm the Account change, click Yes to restart the service.  Click OK to close the properties page.

Ensure the SQL Server service is running with the new domain (service) accoun

Re-run the Prerequisite Check for SCCM 2012 and validate that you do not see the prerequisite for SQL Server service as a warning or failure.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear here. The account used to *run the service* must be a domain account, Network Service, or Local System. This isn't an account inside of SQL.

Comment: As per the question, I have configured the MS SQL 2012 service to login with my domain account and _just my domain account only_. Still getting that same error.

Comment: @Brennan This is the account that SQL itself runs as, not the account you log into SQL Server with.  It is set in the service manager.  Get the properties of the MSSQLSERVER service and change the log on account to a domain account, NETWORK SERVICE or LOCAL SYSTEM.

Comment: @BrennanNeoh the account that you log in with is not the account that runs the SQL Server service. Perhaps you should hire a consultant to assist with this installation.